# C++ operator overriding w/ arguments from 2 classes

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword, overriding

I'm new to object oriented programming and I'm wondering if it's possibile to create an operator for one class which will use arguments from this class and another one, declared by me.

The problem I have to solve is a linear translation on a given point. So I created classes `Point` and `LinearTranslation` and basically what I want to do is to create an operator

```
Point operator* (Point p, LinearTranslation l)
```

which would take `Point p`, do the translation l and then return `Point`. I'm getting weird errors though: `Point operator*(int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type` or that `LinearTranslation has not been declared`.

Is it even possibile?

ok i'm posting only a bit because it's kind of assignment so I have class Point.h

sorry for the mess but I'm trying a bit everything and it's not working for me.

```
#include "LinearTranslation.h"
class Point {
public:
    int N;
    double* coordinates;

public:
    Point(int, double*);
    virtual ~Point();
    double operator[](int a);
    //friend Point operator*(LinearTranslation l);
    friend Point translation(LinearTranslation l);
};

LinearTranslation.h

#include "Point.h"

class LinearTranslation {
private:
    int N;
    double* vector;
    double** matrix;
public:
    //friend class Point;
    LTrans(int,double*,double**);
    LTrans(int);
    virtual ~LTrans();
    void write_vector();
    void write_matrix();
    LinearTranslation operator+(const LinearTranslation&);
    friend Point& translation(LTrans l, Point p);
    //friend Point& operator* (Point p, LTrans l);
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to declare this function before you've declared LinearTransform. Also, please post code.

Comment: ok i edited my post, please help me! I'm sooo stuck...

Comment: 'Trying a bit of everything' does not sound like a good strategy. Maybe you should try one thing until you get it right.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to write an operator that takes two different classes as parameters. However nothing in the posted code does that, so it's a bit hard to help with code you haven't posted.

Comment: The first line you posted `Point operator* (Point p, LinearTranslation l);` is the way to do it. The weird errors you got must have been from other mistakes you made.

Answer (score 0):

in your class declaration:

```
//friend Point operator*(LinearTranslation l);
```

a `friend` operator overloading function takes **two** parameters for the function, you only declare one in your code. The most common example of a friend function is using the overloaded operator *<<* like so:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Point& p);
```

note that this function takes the output as its first parameter, and the point as its second parameter.

Your fix would be to add in your operand to the function

```
friend Point operator*(LinearTranslation l, const int& MULT);
```